# How to get relative path given a parent of unknown location with Python's pathlib?

Tags: python, pathlib

with `pathlib.Path.relative_to` we can get relative paths with:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path("/path/to/foo/bar/thing").relative_to("/path/to/foo")
PosixPath('bar/thing')
```

But what if i don't know the exact path of the parent directory (but i do know its name)?

for example:

- `Path("/path/to/foo/bar/thing")` relative to `"foo"` => `PosixPath('bar/thing')`
- `Path("/path/to/foo/bar/thing")` relative to `"to"` => `PosixPath('foo/bar/thing')`
- `Path("/another_path/to/foo/bar/thing")` relative to `"foo"` => `PosixPath('bar/thing')`

how do i get a relative path relative to an arbitrary parent directory like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
p = Path("/path/to/foo/bar/thing")
relative_to = 'foo'
```

do

```
relative_p = Path(*p.parts[p.parts.index(relative_to) + 1:])
```

Essentially, we grab the parts of the path, find the index of `relative_to` and slice those parts using that index.  Then we pass the sliced parts back to the `Path()` constructor to get back our relative path.

Another option

```
import os
relative_p = Path(str(p).split(f'{os.sep}{relative_to}{os.sep}', maxsplit=1)[-1])
```